# SVN is too slow when commiting/updating

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a laptop with these parameters:

`intel celeron cpu 847 @ 1.10 GHZ
2GB RAM
32 bit windows`

I usually use tortoiseSVN (I've also tried command-line svn). But commiting and updating (cleaning up is fast) is too slow. For a single file it takes 3-4 `minutes` to commit. On another PC those actions take about 3-4 `seconds`, that's why I believe I've not set up something properly or my laptop doesnt meet the requirements.

What can be also a problem?

---

It turns out that I had to disable my antivurs software (Avast). Now everything is fast.

Comment: Is there any network involved?

Comment: Yes, it's a remote svn server. I just tried commiting to another repo on another server, it's taking too long again. :)

Comment: And is the working copy in a local drive or in a network share?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, you know, the working copy is the directory you create with `svn checkout`. It contains the source code that you edit. Is that directory in your laptops's hard disk drive or in some other computer's disk that you access though the local network? Subversion needs lightning fast access to working copies. Additionally, if you're using a very old Subversion release, you might not benefit from recent HTTP performance enhancements.

Comment: The working copy is on my hard drive. Also I'm using the latest release of TortoiseSVN. First the working copy was on my desktop, I tried changing its location to another partition still no effect.

Comment: Antivirus products are well-known to cause massive slowdowns with working copies on Windows. In addition, NTFS has been documented as one of the slower filesystems for Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Commit and update are network related commands (ie with commun ication with svn server), cleaning is a local command (no communication with server, everything needed is stored locally).

If cleaning doesn't take big amount of time, it is probably related to the network bandwith between your computer and the svn server.

Maybe you're behind a RTC modem to reach svn server ;)